# Create new pages from database entries?

Tags: laravel

I've created my first CRUD system for users to post, edit or delete a 'group listing'. These group listings are simply pages on my website where people can suggest meet up events.

I can't figured out how to create the individual web pages that will display the group details to the public?

**What I want**

Once a user creates a group, I need the system to show that group info on a fresh page (I guess using the ID in the url).

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I am fairly new to coding. I appreciate and guidance!

Comment: That's what templates are for. You use the same page (same .php file) but with different data.

Comment: I see. So if I create a group_view.blade.php I can then import the data from the database to that page. I think I can do this, I will give it a try!

Comment: I've created a new page called groups_view.blade.php and added {{$group->group_description}}. For now, I just want to keep it simple. I'm wondering how to asign this to a database group ID, do I need to add anything to the GroupControler? -- currently 'group/index' shows ALL groups, but how I do asign each individual group data to a single page?

Comment: You don't have to asign anything.

Comment: You have to fetch id from the url, so your route has to look as such: `groups/{id}`, then you fetch group of given id and pass it to a view.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you.